# Logout feauture by deleting cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I wanted to create a logout feature by deleting the cookie on the client side. But don't know how to do it

so far this code is not working.
Any help would be appreciated

```
<script>
function clearCookie(name, domain, path) {
    var name = "yoursite.com"
    var domain = ".yoursite.com";
    var path = "/";
    document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + +new Date + "; domain=" + domain + "; path=" + path;
};
```

Comment: Try setting the expiration date in the past.

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Not working

Comment: Check the article in my answer below...good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article from Coder Rocket Fuel
[How to Create, Read, Update, & Delete Cookies in JavaScript](https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/how-to-create-read-update-and-delete-cookies-in-javascript#delete-cookies)

This is some C# I had...it should translate easily.
Again...you set the expiration in the past.

```
 protected void CreateCookie(string location)
 {
     HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie("Location", location);
     httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
     Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
 }
 protected void DeleteCookie()
 {
     HttpCookie httpCookie = new HttpCookie("Location");
     httpCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1);
     Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
 }
```